# Need to list what roles have Modify permission for a given TreeNode (SQL Query)

Tags: sql, kentico

Need to list what roles have Modify permission for a given TreeNode. I need a SQL query.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service! Show some effort and do it yby yoursel.f If you then aencounter a specific problem you can search for it here, and if it not already exists you can ask a new question. thanks.

Comment: OK its bit difficult to find the table structure.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet would be to look at the controls and pages in the which create that section of the Kentico UI and debug the code from there to retrieve the SQL Query which is created by the API when the code is executed.

A good place to start would be here to look at code:

`~/CMSModules/Content/CMSDesk/Properties/Security.aspx`

Having said this, based on the complexity of the table structure and most likely some business logic in the API, you will not get the query to execute properly 100% of the time.  In which I suggest using the API to make your calls.